# Using Fibers in php

Tags: php, fibers

I’m using PHP 8.2.13 and I’m learning about fiber in php. The code that I’m working on is like this:

```php
<?php
$i = 0;

// Create a fiber that prints even numbers
$fiber1 = new Fiber(function () use (&$fiber2) {
    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i += 2) {
        echo "Fiber 1: $i\n";
        // Suspend the fiber and return the next odd number
        Fiber::suspend('fiber1');
        $fiber2->resume($i + 1);
    }
});

// Create a fiber that prints odd numbers
$fiber2 = new Fiber(function ($n) use (&$fiber1) {
    for ($i = $n; $i < 10; $i += 2) {
        echo "Fiber 2: $i\n";
        // Suspend the fiber and return the next even number
        Fiber::suspend('fiber2');
        $i = $fiber1->resume($i + 1);
    }
});

// Start the first fiber
$fiber1->start();
```

And the expected output should be like this:

```
Fiber 1: 0
Fiber 2: 1
Fiber 1: 2
Fiber 2: 3
Fiber 1: 4
Fiber 2: 5
Fiber 1: 6
Fiber 2: 7
Fiber 1: 8
Fiber 2: 9
```

But unfortunately for me the output is like this:

```
Fiber 1: 0
```

I would like help to fix my code, or help me identify my problem.

Comment: call to `Fiber::suspend('fiber1');` suspends execution of fiber1, and it waits for it to resume, so next line (call to fiber2) will not be executed till somebody resumes it, where do you plan to resume it?

Comment: I want fiber1 in `$i = $fiber1->resume($i + 1);` to continue

Comment: but this call in fiber2, which will not be started/resume till somebody resumes fiber1?

Comment: You never start `$fiber2`.

Comment: In each loop, we suspend one and resume the other and pass to the next fiber. In the same way, we continue passing from one fiber to the next until the loop ends.

Comment: @NavidVakili you're suspending current fiber before it can resume another one

Comment: @IłyaBursov beacause cannot resume a fiber that is not suspended

Comment: @Olivier fiber2 should be started during resume

Comment: No, resuming an unstarted fiber throws a `FiberError` exception.

Comment: @Olivier We inserted it into the loop using `use(&$fiber2)` in line 5

Comment: @NavidVakili Have you tried stepping through this with xdebug? I assure you it is functioning as @Olivier suggests. furthermore - if you look at the example at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.fibers.php the code demonstrates very clearly that everything you call after `Fiber::suspend(...)` is not executed until after you resume that fiber. Your code starts `fiber1`, echoes out the expected first line, and then `fiber1` suspends itself again.

Comment: @JoSSte This is true, but I still could not solve the problem by reading Manual.

Comment: @NavidVakili Is your code based on a classroom example? I am not sure (I have no experience with Fiber yet) but it seems like what you are trying to do is not possible with just two fibres. Looking at the code at https://www.php.net/manual/en/fiber.start.php#126695 which basically prints out the numbers 1 - 6 in a single fiber, the flipflop is not between two fibers, but between the main stack and a single fiber.

Comment: As I understand this, the advantage of Fibers is that you can be deep in a stack - find out that you are missing something (e.g. because of another call). pause that stack and then continue the main program stack (which can then start another Fiber thread) to solve the issue and resume the suspended Fiber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fibers are not parallel threads, they are just synchronous functions, which means that you cannot build two functions which will resume each other, because of catch 22 - in order to function f1 to be resumed by f2, f1 should suspend itself, but if f1 suspends itself it cannot resume f2

the best thing you can do is to have 1 primary fiber, which resumes 2nd one:

```
// primary fiber, used to print even numbers and resumes 2nd one when needed
$fiber1 = new Fiber(function () use (&$fiber2) {
    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i += 2) {
        echo "Fiber 1: $i\n";
        $fiber2->resume($i+1); // here we pass value to secondary
    };
});

// secondary fiber, which prints value passed from primary
$fiber2 = new Fiber(function () use (&$fiber1) {
    do {
        $i = Fiber::suspend(); // here we get value from primary
        echo "Fiber 2: $i\n";
    } while ($i < 9);
});

// very important to start fiber2 before fiber1, so primary has something to resume
$fiber2->start();
$fiber1->start();
```

Comment: @NavidVakili This code is fragile. If you change `10` to `11`, you get a `FiberError`.

Comment: @Olivier We can define #m variable and call in each loop . So it is in the second loop $m-1.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to execute two fibers alternatively, here is a way to do it:

```
$fiber1 = new Fiber(function()
{
    for($i=0; $i < 10; $i += 2)
        Fiber::suspend($i);
});

$fiber2 = new Fiber(function()
{
    for($i=1; $i < 10; $i += 2)
        Fiber::suspend($i);
});

printf("Fiber 1 returned %d\n", $fiber1->start());
printf("Fiber 2 returned %d\n", $fiber2->start());

while(!$fiber1->isTerminated() || !$fiber2->isTerminated())
{
    if(!$fiber1->isTerminated())
    {
        $val = $fiber1->resume();
        if($val !== null)
            printf("Fiber 1 returned %d\n", $val);
    }

    if(!$fiber2->isTerminated())
    {
        $val = $fiber2->resume();
        if($val !== null)
            printf("Fiber 2 returned %d\n", $val);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Fiber 1 returned 0
Fiber 2 returned 1
Fiber 1 returned 2
Fiber 2 returned 3
Fiber 1 returned 4
Fiber 2 returned 5
Fiber 1 returned 6
Fiber 2 returned 7
Fiber 1 returned 8
Fiber 2 returned 9
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable effort. Your solution is correct, but because the fiber suspends itself after the start, it is better to place it in the loop of each fiber. Same as code @Iłya Bursov

Comment: @NavidVakili This solution is cleaner. The fibers are totally independant.